# Login with Email and Password in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I Want to login using Email and Password in Djnago so I took help from Youtube and Other StackOverflow's answers but It can't work.

Problem : I can't find out any problem in my code(given below) but IT IS NOT WORKING!!

backends.py(inside 'account' named app)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.object.get(email=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

views.py(inside 'page' named app)

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            print("You are Logged in") 
        else:
            print("Please Enter Valid Email or Password")
    return render(request, "page/login.html")
```

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'account.backends.EmailBackend'
]
```

Note: It works good with default username and password authentication.

Please help me to solve this problem.. 
Thank You!!

Comment: See [custom user model without username field and using email in place of it](https://heemayl.net/posts/django-custom-user-model-without-username-field-and-using-email-in-place-of-it/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ohh!! I get it.
It's because I hed to add 'request' parameter in my authentication method.
Right code is given below

backends.py(inside 'account' named app)

```
class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Now it is work fine!!

Comment: it's a hack it's not a proper solution

Answer (score 0):

By default, `django.contrib.auth.urls` will create a log in page from this pattern:

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

You need to avoid/override this URL.

E.g.
Create a new login URL in your `urls.py`:

```
(r'^emaillogin/$', 'email_login_view'),
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail because I can't understand what to do with URL